# Wirelessly program AVR with Bluetooth device and can be used for data communicationtoo?

Tags: avr, wireless, bluetooth

I am Embedded Software developer. 
Don't have much knowledge of hardware side but am trying some hardware stuff.

Is it  possible to program AVR (ATMega328p) wirelessly using Bluetooth device (HC-05) and then use the same device for data communication?

I have tried this circuit to power ON HC-05 and HC-05 RESET(KEY) by MCU's GPIO and PIN32 of HC-05 is used to reset MCU during programming. The problem is that whenever MCU reset HC-05 also get switched OFF.

Is there any solution or any other circuit that can program AVR and also can communicate data from other Bluetooth devices?

[image: CIRCUIT FOR HC-05 & ATMega328p]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're an embedded programmer, you'd pretty definitely be aware of the concept of *bootloaders*.

Typically, you'd have a minimal firmware (the bootloader) that

1. runs at boot of your ATMega,
2. sets up the bluetooth device,
3. uses it (in any way imaginable) to check whether a firmware update exists,
   · if there's one, receives that and
   · writes it to the flash of the ATMega
4. jumps to the position of the firmware in flash memory.

Pretty much, classical bootloader with update function.